# What can be wrong? Issues with patch 6285

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, patches

I installed patch file on server in directory where all magento files are

than in ssh i wanted to run the patch

i got an error

this is last part of code (it says there is mo folder app/ect/ but it is there??)

What could be causing the issue?

I use Magento 1.9.1.0

```
 ./PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh: line 25: ((: > 0 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "> 0 ")
./PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh: line 32: which: command not found
./PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh: line 33: which: command not found
./PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh: line 34: which: command not found
./PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh: line 35: which: command not found
./PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh: line 36: which: command not found
./PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh: line 25: wc: command not found
./PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh: line 25: ((: > 0 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "> 0 ")
./PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh: line 32: which: command not found
./PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh: line 33: which: command not found
./PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh: line 34: which: command not found
./PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh: line 35: which: command not found
./PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh: line 36: which: command not found
./PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
./PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh: fork: retry: No child processes
./PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh: line 25: wc: command not found
./PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh: line 25: ((: > 0 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "> 0 ")
./PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh: line 32: which: command not found
./PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh: line 33: which: command not found
./PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh: line 34: which: command not found
./PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh: line 35: which: command not found
./PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh: line 36: which: command not found
./PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh: fork: retry: No child processes
./PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh: fork: retry: No child processes
./PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh: fork: retry: No child processes
./PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh: fork: retry: No child processes
./PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
./PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh: line 25: ((: > 0 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "> 0 ")
./PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh: line 32: which: command not found
./PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh: line 33: which: command not found
./PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh: line 34: which: command not found
./PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh: line 35: which: command not found
./PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh: line 36: which: command not found
./PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh: fork: retry: No child processes
./PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh: fork: retry: No child processes
./PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh: fork: retry: No child processes
./PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh: fork: retry: No child processes
./PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
ERROR: "/app/etc/" must exist for proper tool work.
bash-4.2$
```

Comment: Did your download complete successfully? You may have a corrupted file. Also have you placed the patch file within the same folder as index.php?

Comment: Yes i downloaded it (i am on a mac so i got message it could har the computer and if i want to keep the file, answered yes) i uploaded it to the folder where index.php is... the file mentions 1.9.1.1 above... i have 1.9.1.0... could that be it? Though the file was for 1.9.0.0. up to 1.9.1.1

Comment: strange, because i did the previous patches with no issues in May

Comment: Maybe you have something else, than a bash? try `sh PATCH-SUPEE...`

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt don't know what you mean but i see bash-4.2$ don't know what that means though... i'm not good with this stuff unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

As Dave suggested:
Make sure, that you loaded the complete, error-free PATCH file.

Second: don't give `chmod +x` and run it directly `./PATCH-SUPEE...` but instead use a shell wrapper like this: `sh ./PATCH-SUPEE...`

Comment: would it need to be like you state or would it be: sh PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh ... so without ./ - i read in this forum and also from host that i needed to do it like that... and no chmod??

Comment: sh will call the script inside the file, so no need to chmod, as long as you can read it. and `sh` is directory specific, so it doesn't matter whether you use `./` before or not.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt could you ps help me how can i solve this error https://snag.gy/hWXebp.jpg

Comment: @zus feel free to send me an email. I'm freelancer and happy to give you paid support.